# Create Button In A Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello Im new to android i want to ask how do i do intent inside the fragment layout

any answers i would really appreciate

here is the code :

for HomeFragment.java

```
package com.example.splashscreen;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.wifi.hotspot2.pps.HomeSp;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider;
import com.denzcoskun.imageslider.constants.ScaleTypes;
import com.denzcoskun.imageslider.models.SlideModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link HomeFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    // Initiate
    Button button;
    View rootView;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**Button btnMoveActivity = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btnMoveActivity.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

         ImageSlider imageSlider = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.image_slider);

        List<SlideModel> slideModel=new ArrayList<>();
        slideModel.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.kucing2, ScaleTypes.FIT));
        slideModel.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.kucing1,ScaleTypes.FIT));
        slideModel.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.kucing2,ScaleTypes.FIT));

        imageSlider.setImageList(slideModel,ScaleTypes.FIT);
**/

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }



    public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        button.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            switch (view1.getId()){
                case R.id.btn1:
                    Intent moveIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MoveActivity.class); // my button isn't working here
                    startActivity(moveIntent);
                    break;
                }
            });
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.splashscreen">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Splashscreen">
        <activity
            android:name=".Splashscreen"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my button cant do intent and i've try several methods that i cant understand i want to add image slider later but I prefer the button first

thank you for your valuable answer

Comment: it says 'com.example.splashscreen.MainActivity' is not an enclosing class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would work in your case, but if you want to access the `fragment's` host activity and use it for that `Intent` you can try this

```
Activity myParentActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
Intent moveIntent = new Intent(myParentActivity, MoveActivity.class);
```

or this

```
Activity myParentActivity = (MainActivity) requireActivity();
Intent moveIntent = new Intent(myParentActivity, MoveActivity.class);
```

put this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".MoveActivity"/>
```

Comment: thank for help, but it says Cannot resolve symbol 'val' how do i solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention, I though it was Kotlin, I updated my answer as a Java code

Comment: in the log cat it says  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.bookplace/com.example.splashscreen.MoveActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Im curious if this is a homework or an exam... Ill just update my answer as I already started it..

Comment: it suddenly force closing when i press the button

Comment: okay thank you for the answer i use this for my learn purpose im working on a team, my team cant handle coding haha so i try to figure it out

Comment: oh sure now im struggle with image slider XD